# Reading a text file and assigning the values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file with 5 columns:

```
StudentID    UserID    FirstName   LastName   NickName
0122334      7727263   John         Smith      Johnny
8273263      8349734   timmer       Jansen     tim
```

I am trying to read this file in python and assign each of the values to separate variable. Until now, I have read the lines successfully. But, I am not able to assign the values.

Code so far:

```
StudentID = []
UserID = []
FirstName = []
LastName = []
NickName = []

with open(textfile,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract all of them at once:

```
with open(textfile,'r') as f:
    columns = [line.split() for line in f.readlines()]
```

And then create each list from `columns`:

```
StudentID, UserID, firstNAme, LastNAme, NickName = map(list, zip(*columns))
```

First you create a list of lists which is a matrix separated by your given columns line by line. And then it regroup(map) them by making a separated list for each column.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open(textfile, 'r')
for line in f:
    student_id, user_id, first_name, last_name, nick_name = line.split(' ')
StudentId.append(student_id)
UserId.append(user_id)
....
f.close()
```

That is very weird way to write anything though. Much better way is to create class Student that will know the properties of student and how to read from line

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_id=0, user_id=0, first_name='', last_name='', nickname=''):
        self._student_id = student_id
        self._user_id = user_id
        ...

    def from_line(self, line):
        values = line.split(' ')
        self._student_id = int(values[0])
        self._user_id = int(values[1])
        ...

f = open(textfile, 'r')
students = []
for line in f:
    students.append(Student())
    students[-1].from_line(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(textfile,'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        student_id ,user_id, first_name, last_name, nick_name = line.split()
        StudentID.append(student_id)
        UserID.append(user_id) 
        FirstName.append(first_name) 
        LastName.append(last_name)
        NickName.append(nick_name)
```

**Note:** For the naming the list, you are using Camel case convention. In Python, as per `PIP8` for defining the variables you should be using lowercase alphabets separated by underscore `_`. CamelCase variables are for defining the classes.

**Suggestion:**

Since these values belong to the same object, you should be maintaining a single list of objects, as suggested by [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6664305/dmitry-torba) OR, simply store a list of `list`.

For example:

```
persons = []
with open(textfile,'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        persons.append(line.split())

print persons
# [['0122334', '7727263', 'John', 'Smith', 'Johnny'],
#  ['8273263', '8349734', 'timmer', 'Jansen', 'tim']]
```

Here you'll have `StudentID`, `UserID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `NickName` at `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` index respectively.

Comment: `for item, collection in zip(line.split(),[StudentID, UserID, FirstName, LastName, NickName]):collection.append(item)`

Comment: @Steven: Add it as an answer. It will be helpful for others.